# how to display selected horizontal menu

Tags: html, css

I have a 4 item menu, each of which displays the name of the item as well as the nav icon (using css sprite).  Here is my markup/css:

```
ul { list-style:none outside none; }
ul li {
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    height:100px;
}
ul li a {
    background-image:url('sprite.png');
    color:#FFF;
    display:block;
    height:10px;
    padding-top:20px;
    text-align:center;
    width:50px;
}

ul li.a a { background-position:0px 0px; }
ul li.b a { background-position:-50px 0px }
ul li.c a { background-position:-100px 0px }
ul li.d a { background-position:-150px 0px }    
-----------------------------------------------------------------
<ul>
    <li class="a"><a href="a">A</a></li>
    <li class="b"><a href="b">B</a></li>
    <li class="c"><a href="c">C</a></li>
    <li class="d"><a href="d">D</a></li>
</ul>
```

This all works fine, but say I want to show a different effect on the currently selected item. Specifically, I want to have a different background color, a different icon, and different color text.  What's the best way to do this?  The only way I can think of is adding a 'selected' class to the `<li>` which I specificy a different background-color and also adding a 'selected' class to the `<a>` which I specifiy a different background-image and a different color of text.

Something like:

```
ul li.selected { background-color:#FFF; }
ul li a { color:#000; }
ul li.a a.selected { background-position:-250px 0px; }
ul li.b a.selected { background-position:-300px 0px; }
ul li.c a.selected { background-position:-350px 0px; }
ul li.d a.selected { background-position:-400px 0px; }
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
<ul>
    <li class="a selected"><a class="selected" href="a">A</a></li>
    <li class="b"><a href="b">B</a></li>
    <li class="c"><a href="c">C</a></li>
    <li class="d"><a href="d">D</a></li>
</ul>
```

Which don't get me wrong I can do it this way, but I just feel like it's not the way it's supposed to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the cascade in the CSS to get the effect you want with a little bit less code.

Apply the `.selected` to the `li` and then go for the double class.

```
ul li.selected { background-color:#FFF; }
ul li.a.selected a { background-position:-250px 0px; }
ul li.b.selected a { background-position:-300px 0px; }
ul li.c.selected a { background-position:-350px 0px; }
ul li.d.selected a { background-position:-400px 0px; }
```

Basically, you are *chaining* the classes.

This way, you don't need to add a `selected` class to both the `li` and the `a`.  Your HTML would be simplified, like so (no second `selected` class)

```
<ul>
    <li class="a selected"><a href="a">A</a></li>
    <li class="b"><a href="b">B</a></li>
    <li class="c"><a href="c">C</a></li>
    <li class="d"><a href="d">D</a></li>
</ul>
```

Details from the spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html

Comment: Yeah I thought about the double class but doesn't this only work on modern browsers? I could've sworn double class ins't supported in the older browsers but I could be wrong.

Comment: I believe all the browsers back to IE7 support this.  (As long as IE7 is not in Quirks mode.)